# How can we add imported Developer certificates in Mac can be added to key chain

Tags: macos, code-signing

I googled a lot for this solution, but couldn't find a proper one. when i try to add imported certificate in key chain by using following

sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k “/Library/Keychains/System.keychain”       “/private/tmp/certs/certname.cer”

I get an error saying

SecCertificateAddToKeychain: Unknown format in import

In some of my searches i found that certificate may be corrupted while importing from one machine to another. So i used different protocols for file transfer. But that doesn't affected my error.
Please some one look in to it and give me a clue to proceed

Answer (score 3):

Today i had the same issue, I solved as reported here: [link to macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/os-x-support-of-certificate-key-length.1387863/)

The issue is:
The certificate has a key length of 8192 bits, signature algorithm of SHA256RSA.
Mac OS won't import CA certs with this lenght, so:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security RSAMaxKeySize -int 8192
```

and after a reboot I was able to import it.